# Git Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I already have created the ssh key to my network drive. Only issue is that when network drive is not accessible then my git pull/push not worked due to no ssh key found. So I decided to add new key to my windows drive. 
I added the the new ssh key but when I pull/push code I received below error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I run below command

```
1) $ eval `ssh-agent` 
2) ssh-add /d/ssh/id_rsa
```

After that I am able to pull/push. But again there is problem whenever I restart my computer I need to run that 2 commands. This is not good solution to run every time. So is there any good solution so that I no need to run command.

**Note:**  I already deleted all the previous ssh key from my network drive.

**UPDATED**

After I run `ssh -vvv bitbucket.org` command the output is below.

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'Azam.Alvi'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/z/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /z/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaYXaGp1A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/z/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /z/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/z/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /z/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 104.192.143.1
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /z/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /d/ssh/id_rsa (0x600072470),
debug2: key: /z/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /z/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /z/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /z/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /d/ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /z/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /z/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /z/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /z/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /z/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /z/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /z/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /z/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `ssh_config` with

```
Host git_hostname # probably bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile /d/ssh/id_rsa
```

It should be in `~/.ssh/config`. You should be able to find out what configuration is your client reading when running `ssh -vvv bitbucket.org`.

Comment: I am using windows, so where should I create this file

Comment: "*You should be able to find out what configuration is your client reading when running `ssh -vvv bitbucket.org`.*"

Comment: when I try to find using ssh -vvv then mostly I found `/z/.ssh/*` path which was network path and now it is not exist anymore.

Comment: Update the question with the whole log. from the above command.

Comment: Use either global config in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or local in `/z/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 5):

It can also happen when u added SSH support in your repository. And can be fixed by following steps :

1. Goto SSH

   ```
   cd ~/.ssh
   ```
2. List existing Keys

   ```
   ls -al ~/.ssh
   ```
3. Use this command to create the SSH keys

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
   ```
4. Use this command to start your ssh-agent if it's not already running

   ```
   eval `ssh-agent`
   ```
5. Then add your private key file to SSH

   ```
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/<private_key_file>
   ```
6. Copy and paste your key in Bitbucket/ Github with

   ```
   cat ~/.ssh/<public_key_file> | pbcopy
   ```
7. Sometime it does not persists between reboot. Then you have to add below lines in .ssh/config (For Mac)

   ```
   Host *
       UseKeychain yes
       AddKeysToAgent yes
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<private_key_file>
   ```
8. In case if you want to use multiple Git accounts. Lets say you have to Github and Bitbucket both on a system. Then you need to create separate SSH keys for GitHub and Bitbucket and you mention both in the config file like below.

   ```
   Host *
       UseKeychain yes
       AddKeysToAgent yes

   #Bitbucket
       Host bitbucket.org
       User git
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bb-ssh-key

   #GitHub
       Host github.com
       User git
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-ssh-key
   ```