# Git over ssh: Permission denied public key

Tags: linux, git, ssh, rsa

I have a problem with cloning public git repositories. My .ssh folder looks like this:

```
XXXXXX@XXXXXXXX:~/.ssh$ ls -ll
-rw------- 1 XXXXX XXXXX  398 Mar 17 10:03 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r-- 1 XXXXX XXXXX  182 Mar 21 12:06 config
-rw------- 1 XXXXX XXXXX 3243 Mar 21 10:42 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXXX XXXXX  745 Mar 21 10:42 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 XXXXX XXXXX 1376 Mar 19 12:21 known_hosts
```

The output of the ssh connection test looks like this:

```
XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXXXx:~/.ssh$ ssh -Tvvvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec connect -H XX.X.XX.XX:8080 github.com 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-d48c3acd
debug1: no match: babeld-d48c3acd
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbk6kXUpJWGl7E1IUOCspRomTxdCARLwiKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa (0x5627d1404e70), agent
debug2: key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:fqtAIC3IejKfEAqUy34hBKy0EnLOnMxQ/5wbGgqFGOk /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The keys were generated using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "XXXX@XXXX.com"
```

I also walked through this github help page (https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey):

```
XXXXX@XXXXXX:~/.ssh$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 21483
XXXXX@XXXXXX:~/.ssh$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
XXXXX@XXXXXX:~/.ssh$ ssh-add id_rsa
Identity added: id_rsa (id_rsa)
XXXXX@XXXXXX:~/.ssh$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:fqtCIk3IDjkOEBqUp34hsKy0EnLOnNZQ/5wMXjqFgOk id_rsa (RSA)
```

I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144090/6228450 (restart ssh afterwards). Does not work either.

Anybody have another idea what the issue is?

Comment: It looks like you only have one key, id_rsa. According to the debug output, ssh offered id_rsa to the remote server, and the remote server didn't accept it. If that's the key that you're expecting to work, it's apparently not set up correctly on the server side.

Comment: I have no keys configured on the github side, but public repositories should work eitherway since I am using the github user, right? I simply want to clone public repositories.

Comment: Ok by adding the public key to my git provider I can clone the repo, but that means I have to create an account for everything I want to clone ...

Comment: If you plan to authenticate to GitHub via ssh, you need *an* identity that you will present to them that they will recognize. You do not need an account per repository: having identified you as you, GitHub will now give you access to (a) all public repositories **and** (b) all repositories that *are not* public but *are* accessible to the identity they have verified that you presented.

Comment: Note that you can access *public* repositories via un-authenticated http or https. The issue with accessing them via ssh is that to get *anything* through ssh, you must first present an identity that the ssh service can verify.

Comment: Ok, cloning via ssh works now in general - the only issue arises when I try to clone a repository "git://" then I get a name resolution error because I am behind a proxy. For http and https it works - anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Tty and recreate one:

- with the old format
- without passphrase (for at least testing)

That is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P "" -C "XXXX@XXXX.com"
```

Do copy the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public key to your GitHub SSH keys setting page.